# Python, put Json-Data in a variable

Tags: python, json

I want to put Json-File data in to individual variables. So I can use the variables for otherthings. Im able to create a Json-file from inputs from a other QDialog. The next move is to get the inputs back out of the Json-File and insert it into individual variables.
So json:Line1 into self.line1Config and so on.

```
self.jsonfile = str(self.tn+'.json')

def WriteJSON(self):

    self.NewConfigJSON = {}
    self.NewConfigJSON['configs'] = []
    self.NewConfigJSON['configs'].append({
        'Line1':  str(self.CreatNewJsonW.Line1),
        'Line2':  str(self.CreatNewJsonW.Line2),
        'Line3':  str(self.CreatNewJsonW.Line3)
    })
    jsonString = json.dumps(self.NewConfigJSON)
    jsonFile = open(self.jsonfile, 'w')
    jsonFile.write(jsonString)
    jsonFile.close()
```

With the code below, it wont work:

```
  def CheckIfJsonFileIsAlreadyThere(self):
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(self.jsonfile) == True:
            data = json.loads(self.jsonfile)

            for daten in data:
                self.line1Config = daten['Line1']
                self.line2Config = daten['Line2']
                self.line3Config = daten['Line3']
        else:
            raise Exception
         
    except Exception:
        self.label_ShowUserText("There are no configuration yet. Please create some 
        configuartions")
        self.label_ShowUserText.setStyleSheet("color: black; font: 12pt \"Arial\";")
```

The Error Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\path", line 90, in CheckIfJsonFileIsAlreadyThere
    data = json.loads(self.jsonfile)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 11 (char 10)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\path", line 38, in <module>
    MainWindow = mainwindow()
  File "path", line 21, in __init__
    self.d = Generator_Dialog(self)
  File "c:\path", line 55, in __init__
    self.CheckIfJsonFileIsAlreadyThere()
  File "c:path", line 100, in CheckIfJsonFileIsAlreadyThere
    self.label_ShowUserText("There are no configuration yet. Please create some configuartions")
TypeError: 'QLabel' object is not callable
```

Comment: What are the contents of the JSON file?

Comment: {"Configs": [{"Line1": "some text", "Line2": "some text", "Line3": "some text"}]} @ScottHunter

Comment: you are using `json.loads()`, which expects the serialized JSON data as a parameter,  but you are passing there `self.jsonfile`, which is the name of the JSON file, that won't work. You have to pass there content of the file.

Comment: Sorry, Im new programer. I didn't understand what you mean. Or what I should do. 
@yedpodtrzitko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have here two problems:

1. json.loads needs a string and not a path. Change it to:

   ```
   with open(self.jsonfile) as jsonfile:
        data = json.load(jsonfile)
   ```
2. You have forgotten your "Config" Level in your JSON structure:

   ```
    for daten in data["Config"]:
         self.line1Config = daten['Line1']
         self.line2Config = daten['Line2']
         self.line3Config = daten['Line3']
   ```

I created a minimal working example for you: https://www.online-python.com/ZoGQWjlehI

Answer (score 1):

Since the JSON document comes from a file specifically from `self.jsonfile = str(self.tn+'.json')`, then use `json.load()` instead of `json.loads()`:

- [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)

  > Deserialize s (**a str, bytes or bytearray instance** containing a JSON document) to a Python object
- [json.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)

  > Deserialize fp (a `.read()`-supporting **text file or binary file** containing a JSON document) to a Python object

Change this line:

```
data = json.loads(self.jsonfile)
```

To

```
with open(self.jsonfile) as opened_file:
    data = json.load(opened_file)
```

Comment: I did.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\path", line 94, in CheckIfJsonFileIsAlreadyThere
    self.line1Config = daten['Line1']
TypeError: string indices must be integers

What is here the Problem?

Comment: That means you are now already reading the contents of the file :) Can you share the contents of your `.json` file?

Comment: {"Configs": [{"Line1": "some text", "Line2": "some text", "Line3": "some text"}]}